# How do I set new product's category?

Tags: product, category, magento-1.9

I'd like to assign new product to a default category automatically, so I won't have to pick the category checkbox in Categories tab every time I create a product.

I tried this in my module's Observer.php:

```
    public function initProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        (...)

        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $productData = $product->getData();

        $productCatalog = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
        $productCatalog->setCategoryIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId()));
        $productCatalog->save();
    }
```

but it won't set the category.

Answer (score 1):

Use the event **catalog_product_new_action**

Example usage of catalog_product_new_action can be found here: http://swarminglabs.com/setting-default-product-values-in-magento/

Comment: it's offtopic, nothing about product's category there

Comment: @van_folmert That's true, product categories is not covered in the link. As I think the problems is the wrong Event **initProduct** I wanted to quickly link to a ressource with the proper use of **catalog_product_new_action**. (Will change the text of my answer slightly.)